# Laravel Database

Tags: database, laravel

I have a problem i want to create a database command with variables but it doesnt work at all.
I am new to Laravel.
if i write in the sql command K.id=W.Kid it works. But i want to know how this works with variables.

```
  if(request('nachname'))
  {
    $nachnamesuchen = request('nachname');
    $nachnameanzeigen = $nachnamesuchen;
  }
  else
  {
    $nachnamesuchen='%';
    $nachnameanzeigen=null;
  }
  if(request('ortadden')!=null)
  {
    $ortaddensuchen=request('ortadden');
    $ortanzeigen=$ortaddensuchen;

    $test="K.id";
    $test1="W.Kid";

  }
  else
  {
    $ortaddensuchen='%';
    $ortanzeigen=null;
    $test='1';
    $test1='1';

  }
  $Datenzumsuchen=array(
                          'Vorname'=>$vornameanzeigen,
                          'Nachname'=>$nachnameanzeigen,
                          'Ort'=>$ortanzeigen,
                        );
      $Kundenanzeigen=DB::select('select K.vorname,K.nachname,K.id from Kundes AS K,
      wunschorte AS W where K.vorname like ? and K.nachname like ? and W.Wunschort like ? and ?=?',
      [$vornamesuchen,$nachnamesuchen,$ortaddensuchen,$test,$test1]);
```

Comment: You really need to read this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries It looks like you are still trying to run RAW sql. You can do this but not the way you are and I would suggest using the query builder as it keeps things nice and tidy.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a string, so you can just put those variables in them:

```
DB::select('select K.vorname,K.nachname,K.id from Kundes AS K, 
wunschorte AS W where K.vorname like '.$vornameanzeigen.' AND ...
```

But I would suggest you take a look at Eloquent, which is Laravel's way of database interaction, it makes queries a lot less complicated and more ordered (in my opinion).
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent